# Libcurl compiling error: "undefined reference to `__mingw_basename'"

Tags: c++, mingw, libcurl, undefined-reference

This question has already been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835352/get-undefined-reference-to-mingw-basename-errors-while-compiling-curl-7-46-0), but no answers. I am trying to link statically libcurl on Windows with GNU GCC compiler (using last curl version 7.51) I have added ws2_32.a and libcurl.a to the linked libraries with the option `-static` and in search directories I have included curl\include and the /lib. And I added CURL_STATICLIB in defines.

Build Log:

```
mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g -std=c++11 -DCURL_STATICLIB -IC:\Libcurl\static_built\include -IC:\c++\Tutorials\.cbp\libCurl -c C:\c++\Tutorials\.cbp\libCurl\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\Libcurl\static_built\lib -o bin\Debug\libCurl\.exe.exe obj\Debug\main.o  -static  C:\Libcurl\static_built\lib\libcurl.a C:\MinGW\lib\libws2_32.a
C:\Libcurl\static_built\lib\libcurl.a(libcurl_la-formdata.o):formdata.c:(.text+0x491): undefined reference to `__mingw_basename'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Particularly the error:

```
undefined reference to `__mingw_basename'
```

Comment: I need to link any other library?

Comment: "libgen" perpaps? `-lgen` on the command line?

Comment: I included `#include <libgen.h>` but still  undefined reference to `__mingw_basename'

Comment: You need to *link* with the correct lib, just #including the right header isn't enough

Comment: I found libgenerate.dll.a which is located at `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\lib\perl5\vendor_perl\5.8\msys\auto\B\Generate`. After linking it it pops up the same error, wich seem to me that I have linked another library. Where can I find it, if it is not that one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link `libmingwex.a` in order to solve the problem: `undefined reference to __mingw_basename'`. This library is located at MinGW/libs.